# Pro Tools 10 - First Impressions?

Tags: pro-tools, daw

Anybody up and running with it yet? How's the new channel strip? Has anyone tested the new caching and tried running a session over a network yet?

I'm probably going to wait a bit because I just can't risk an upgrade at the moment. But I would love to hear any first impressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm absolutely loving having clip gain.  So much faster than constantly using audiosuite's gain, even with it on a key command.

Also having multiple audiosuite windows open at the same time is great.

Channelstrip is a nice plug.  I'm not sure if it'll replace any of my favorites, but it sounds very good, and the dynamics section is really killer.  Very light on cpu too.

Haven't tried RAM caching yet, I've only had it installed for 2 days and I'm waiting until I have a giant mix to really be able to utilize it properly...

Also, everything just runs smoother.  You can actually now move an region while playing, and hear the change in real time, as opposed to having to stop and start again.

The one gripe I have is the changing of everything that used the word "Region" to "Clip."  It may be a superficial annoyance, but it's annoying nonetheless.

I'm very happy with HD10.  I do think the asking price is too high, but the new features have already sped up my workflow quite a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Still no offline bounce though...

Answer (score 2):

At least with the AAX plugin format they can now process either on the host or on their new DSP boards, meaning offline/faster than realtime bouncing is much more achievable than in the TDM days - seems like a strategy to me.
Lots of post features in 10 - disk cache for big sessions is a god send and more field recorder features - the ability to set a "guide" track for matches/expansions stuff like that.
32bit plugin architecture and 64bit mixer - lots of headroom, great for mixing. Interleaved support for sending crap back and forth to editorial. All good features to smooth pain points IMHO.

Comment: there seems to be some misunderstanding going around concerning the new AAX format. the two versions are analogous to RTAS and TDM. AAX Native use the host processor only, they will not be processed by the DSP hardware acceleration boards. only AAX DSP will actually be processed on the boards.

Comment: ok, so i just read on the Frank Filipanti's post on the DUC, and I was wrong. it will be POSSIBLE to create plug-ins that can run in either Native or DSP format. it's still more code intensive to do so, and will be up to manufacturers to take that step if they wish to. i believe we're still going to see, on the whole, a continued separation between Native and DSP from 3rd party developers going forward. one interesting note in the article though, DSP plug-ins should be able to run natively in the AAX format regardless. the difficulty is making Native run as DSP.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I have not tried PT10 yet, however they way they have handled its presentation thusfar has left me unimpressed and planning to stay on PT8 until they get their act together.

Not impressed by their marketing strategy, or lack of maintaining good solidarity from the get go.  Somehow anyone who's got CPTK1 or 2 gets a "free-pass" to run it with PT10 at no extra charge, but if anyone missed out on upgrading their DVTK or MPTK to CPTK for $350 during  PT9, we're all SOL and have to buy CPTK for a full $2000.  Hopefully that's just a mistake in their store, but it's lack of a united front.  And that they didn't mention support for the 002/003, but buried in their FAQ on their support page the mention support for those boxes and PT10 is the last version to officially support them.  Had to dig around to discover in a fine-print note that CPTK is still required for all the "HD features" - they don't disclose this up front and delineate if you need it.  Maybe so you buy the upgrade, realize you don't have the cool HD features, then realize you have to play them $2000 to pass go?  So far it's all come across disorganized and shady to me.

And here's the funny part:

PT8 or lower to PT9 to PT10 = $550

PT8 or lower to PT10 = $500

Accounting error much?  Another example of a lack of a united front.

Sorry for this being somewhat of a rant.  Now I'm realizing why so many stages and facilities have held onto older versions for so long... it's such a mess to try to upgrade and maintain modular transparency in my opinion.  Why Avid still doesn't get this is beyond me.  The plugin vendors know whats up (see: Waves drastic new pricing), but Avid's still a space cadet.

In conclusion, my initial reaction to ProTools 10's release was this: "Avid, I'm taking away your final Man card"

**EDIT:** An email response from the Avid store did state that upgrade options fro DVTK 1, 2, and MPTK are coming.  Good to hear that steps in the right direction are being made.  Still a pretty bad PR mess on their part, but at least there's some progress.

Comment: @Stavrosound do you reckon it's worth getting onto 9 first and then upgrading to 10. Couple of online stores still selling the crossgrade from LE to PT 9

Comment: I think it all depends upon the person and their needs.  I'm treating 9 like Win Vista (in that I'[m gunna pass over it).  For me though the issue is that under Win 32, PreoTools 9 and 10 have bugs right now that broke the ability to do file imports (aside from using the import audio box).  This means that all drag-n-drop imports and Soundminer's spot to timeline got broken, so upgrading to 9 would be a death wish for me.  They are slated to fix the problem for 9 and 10 soon, so once that is fixed, then I'll probably upgrade to 10 at some point.

Comment: 1 month on and still no updates on the DVTK upgrade options. But at the moment, it seems to me that it's more worthwhile getting an Mbox Mini w/ PT 9 (free upgrade to 10) at under $600. Selling away the Mini means it's cheaper than any of their upgrade options, and keeping it for me means it's a decent audio interface for $100.

Answer (score 1):

I got protools 9 early october so they sent me a free upgrade to 10. I have been fighting 10 with crashes dae errors. I have done evrything to deleting old pt preferences to clean installs. It works for a few sessions then i will try to open a seesion or make a new session and crash. I have to reinstall it to get to work again. Back to 9. 0. 3. Gona have to wait till they fix that crap. New protools always has glitches in the begining but this is the worst one yet. Atleast i could open the first releases in the past. Geeez! I am impressed with some of the new features. Unfortunatly this experience has put a dent in my confidence with protools. I cant work and be creative on an extremly unstable daw. Who can? You would think avid would think about the guys like me who are the professionals and dont have time for these issues. 10 is unacceptable in my opinion. Wait for updates b4 trying it unless you have time to screw around.

Comment: hi rocka, is your caps lock button stuck or do you always type your texts in capitals? it makes it very hard to get your message..

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Snow Leopard 10.6.8. Its the minimum requirement for PT 10. Sorry bout the caps thing:-)

Comment: Have you tried installing the 10.6.8 Combo update? 

Answer (score 1):

Yes, PT 10 does NOT run good on Snow Leopard. I updated to lion, reinstalled 10, found that i had a couple plugins i had to update like. Flux Verb Session will not run on 10 till you update to the latest version. It crashes PT at loading plugins stage. I am stable and running strong with PT 10 in OSX Lion now. I have most all plugins and they are all there and running well, so if anyone is wondering about plugins in lion with PT10 , Waves complete, Native Instruments, Rob Papen, Kontakt 4 and 5, Linplug, DSP, PSP, iZotope, Spectrasonics... are all running fine. I am posting that info cuz i had that question and noone could answer it for me. Just remember to do a safe uninstall of 9 or 8 or you will have to reinstall all your plugins. Note*** Nexus 2 runs fine but does need an update that is not available yet by refx. The GUI looks a little funny on my system but WORKS fine. Hope this helps:-) I am curious about the 32 bit recording. Once i use it i will post info. BTW Channel strip is a nice plugin

Answer (score 1):

<del>anyone else with a more definitive report on PT10 and 10.6.8?</del>

I doubt if that many PT users have jumped onto Lion..?

edit: I held off upgrading for some time, anticipating a .0.1 release, but finally took the plunge and installed PT10 over PT9. iLok made this slightly less straightforward but from there onwards it was pretty smooth, and I was pleasantly surprised that nothing (as far as I could see) broke in the process. My preferences did get trashed though. I find that awkward, apparently someone at Avid didn't get the message that it's 2011 and this should magically work. Credit to them for turning my PT9 license into a 9+10 bundle - comforting.

Clip-based gain brings a whole new workflow for me, and the channel strip plugin is nice. Still getting my head around Audiosuite and handles, and how they work (or not) when I have clip gain already in.

Am already in the middle of a little project, with nothing unexpected in terms of routing/IO. If anything, things feel slightly more straightforward now. I did leave the system idling with a session open for hours, which also worked fine (I factor this in, when judging stability).

Liked that I didn't have to re-download all content I already had installed. Just the PT10 installer. Still not sure about the virtual instruments though.

Finally, using this on Snow Leopard 10.6.8 with no issues so far.

Answer (score 0):

i have been trying to order an education version on PT9 for a few weeks now and apparently there was none in AUS so they ordered me one but its been taking so long and they said there was a hold up at avid.

the lady i have been speaking to said shes not sure when PT10 will come to AUS, basically now im not sure weather to just get PT10 or continue with my plan to get PT9. so ill be watching this space to see what you guys think of it. i guess im just worried if its gonna be buggy for a while.

clip based gain sounds handy though, i remember using it when i used cubase around 5 years ago and when i switched to logic it was one of the most annoying things because i was so used to it.

Answer (score 0):

here's a link to a roundup of new features, made by Jamie Hardt: [designing sound link](http://designingsound.org/2011/10/pro-tools-10-at-aes/)

@stavrosound: i totally feel your pain, i'm also without the CPTK and although it's ok for stereo and editing, i am saving up for the big punch... buying a 2K dongle :(

update:
shaun farley wrote down an elaboration on the article by jamie.
[update by shaun farley](http://designingsound.org/2011/10/pro-tools-1-at-aes-part-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks look similar to Pro Tools 9, but it does seem to run slightly faster on my MacBook Pro.  Installation was easy and everything is stable.  Will test it with Lion tomorrow.

I am enjoying using the channel strip, very easy to use as well as being nice and clean.

Answer (score 0):

Looks very much like Pro Tools is trying to catch up with Nuendo. It now got a lot of the Nuendo features that makes working in post much quicker. But still a few important features to go until it is even with Nuendo.

Nevertheless, this update really makes me think of working in Pro Tools again.

Comment: After seeing them demo at AES this last weekend. I agree, they are just playing catch up with Nuendo. I hate the fact that Pro Tools has such a big market share. AES only helped show this, as the booth was very prominent and very loud.


Answer (score 0):

I have protools 10, running MacBook Pro with OS x 10.6.8 core i7 2.66GHz, Focusrite Saffire Pro 40, ProjectMix i/o, ART Digital MPA ii. I was deep into a session things started slowing down, so i saved and closed PT10 to open back up and now I get OS Compatibility Issues, no Support from Avid so far. But this is F***ing bullshit. I am about to have to uninstall PT10 and Reinstall PT9 or maybe better yet take it back to good ole stable PT 7.4.

UPGRADE TO LION IF YOU ARE GOING TO TRY AND RUN PROTOOLS 10.

PT 10 such-soon-therafter birth is due to PT9 compatibility with mac's new OS; Lion.

Answer (score 0):

PT 10 cannot run xpand2 at all...its not a new bug but if this is an issue for anyone forget installing at present..also it has tacky 'marketplace' menu in session..

Answer (score 0):

hi,
I just installed pro tools 10 and I'm also running lion but I have a problem with the midi , I use a 003. I've installed the driver (latest) and still doesn't recognize it.  Anyone with the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

CLIP GAIN!!

Okay, well, maybe it's not THAT exciting....

From what I've seen of the update I'm quite impressed.  Clip gain and the ability to load a session directly into the RAM of a system (especially on a host-based system) are probably the most useful features in my mind.

To echo the above sentiment - DEFINITELY upgrade to Lion.  Haven't had a chance to test midi though....that may be an issue with support for the 003 itself.

Answer (score 0):

Pro tools and clip gain, welcome to twenty first century.